# What is the function of SetDefaultItem?

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc

i just want to know what is the function of `DefaultItem`, what is the difference between general `MenuItem` and it, except bold-font... thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking in the [MSDN Menu Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647553.aspx) leads to this answer.

> A submenu can contain one default menu item. When the user opens a submenu by double-clicking, the system sends a command message to the menu's owner window and closes the menu as if the default command item had been chosen. If there is no default command item, the submenu remains open. To retrieve and set the default item for a submenu, use the GetMenuDefaultItem and SetMenuDefaultItem functions.

Answer (score 1):

It's mostly a visual affordance.  Raymond Chen explains `SetDefaultItem` on his *The Old New Thing* site: [What does boldface on a menu mean?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/09/29/235737.aspx)